# ADO.NET Data Services with EF implementing table per concrete type (TPCT) inheritance

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I am working with a SQL data source that has duplicate data in multiple tables. I have no control over the database. For my project, I've created an EF model and an ADO.NET data service (using VS 2008) that exposes it. I also have a .NET client application that consumes the service.

Now, these db tables have a large number of fields common, which I need to hydrate in my client before sending an insert request to the service. So, wanting to avoid repetitive code, I created an abstract base class in my EF model and put all the common properties in it. The entity set name of this base class is `OrderEntries`. One of the entities inheriting from it is called `OEORDH`. It maps to a db table. To expose this entity, I created a WebGet service method because the query uses `OfType` method, which has no supported translation to ATOM; hence I can't use it in my client. Here's the method:

```
<WebGet()> _
Public Function Orders() As IQueryable(Of OEORDH)
    Dim results = From x In Me.CurrentDataSource.OrderEntries.OfType(Of OEORDH)()
    Return results
End Function
```

When I access this method in the browser (http://localhost:1187/MyService.svc/Orders), I get a very generic error back:

```
<link rel="self" title="Orders" href="Orders" />
  <m:error>
    <m:code></m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred while processing this request.</m:message>
  </m:error>
```

But I know that the query gets called, and moreover, when I watch the Locals window in debug, I see that it returns the right collection of objects. Other web methods that query non-inheriting entities work just fine. What is wrong?

**UPDATE**
I followed Steve's advice and set `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` to true. I also set `UseVerboseErrors` to true. The trace log now shows that the exception being thrown is System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException, which is still pretty generic. I searched the web, but didn't find anything concrete. The message is: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportReplyChannelAcceptor+TransportReplyChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted. Here's the stack content:

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfAborted()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.EndDequeue(IAsyncResult result, TDisposable&amp; item)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReplyChannel.EndTryReceiveRequest(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; context)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ReplyChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; requestContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; requestContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueue`1.Shutdown(CommunicationObject communicationObject)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.OnClosing()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ReplyChannelBinder.Abort()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnAbort()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
System.Data.Services.DelegateBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriter.WriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpStreamMessageEncoderFactory.HttpStreamMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Stream stream)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpStreamMessageEncoderFactory.HttpStreamMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncoderFactory.WebMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessageCleanup(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Dispatch(MessageRpc&amp; rpc, Boolean isOperationContextSet)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, ItemDequeuedCallback dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(TDisposable item, ItemDequeuedCallback dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, ItemDequeuedCallback dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, ItemDequeuedCallback callback)
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
System.ServiceModel.PartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke2()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ProcessCallbacks()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.CompletionCallback(Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Comment: In order to get a more meaningful error message, try putting [System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)] on top of your data services class.

Comment: You can use $filter=isof(MyNS.OEORDH) to basically ask for the OfType query on the server (it's not exactly the same, but the results should be the same. See for more details: http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions#FilterSystemQueryOption

Comment: Thanks Vitek. I'll check out the docs